# Node.js, Error: Unknown system error -122

Tags: node.js

While trying to upload a new image with node.js, I did get the following error

```
message : 
"Error: Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, open 'fooBar/file-sample_150kB.pdf'"
_status: 500
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the server **not** having **enough space** to save the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned error is not a standard Node.js error. It seems to be related to a system-specific issue or an issue within the library or code you are using for file upload. You need to verify the

- **File Path and Name**: Ensure that file path and name is correct. It seems like you are trying to upload a PDF file (file-sample_150kB.pdf) instead of an image. Make sure you are providing the correct file path and name for the image file
- **Check File Existence**: Before attempting to open or upload the file, check if the file exists at the specified path. You can use the fs module to check the existence of the file.

  ```
  const fs = require('fs');
   const filePath = 'fooBar/file-sample_150kB.pdf';

   if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
   // Proceed with file upload logic
   } else {
     console.error('File not found:', filePath);
     // Handle the error appropriately
   }
  ```